# Need some help to figure out why mozMobileMessage(SMS) function is not working with setInterval to send scheduled SMS to a mobile phone

Tags: javascript, sms, settimeout, setinterval, kaios

Been trying to get to the bottom of this for a couple of days now. For some reasons the `mozMobileMessage` function doesn't seem to work properly with setIntervals (using the script on KaiOS 2.5 app). The code below (where the mobile number is captured as part of the app) only ever sends a single SMS message to the phone. Any idea how to fix this? I'd like the message to be sent at set intervals for a set duration:

```
let timerId = setInterval(navigator.mozMobileMessage.send(mobileNumberInput.value, "Hello"), 10000);
setTimeout(() => {clearInterval(timerId);}, 40000);
```

I've tried to call `mozMobileMessage` several times separately within the code as per below to check if this could be to do with some function limitations. But calling the function manually within the code will work fine and sends an SMS as many times as the functions is called:

```
navigator.mozMobileMessage.send(mobileNumberInput.value, "Hello");
navigator.mozMobileMessage.send(mobileNumberInput.value, "Hello");
navigator.mozMobileMessage.send(mobileNumberInput.value, "Hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing invalidate parameters to `setInterval` function.

By shorthand, you can to use this syntax for both `setInterval` and `setTimeout`

```
setInterval(function_name,delay,...parameters_for_function_to_be_called);
```

**Explanation**

1. First parameter is a function name, you don't have to call it initially timers will do for you.
2. Second parameter is delay obviously in seconds.
3. Finally remaining passed `parameters` are be the `arguments` for your function that passed in first `parameter`.

Let says for example, I have the following function

```js
function sendMessage(number,message){
   console.log(number, message);
}
 
const interval = setInterval(sendMessage,1000,1234567890,'hello');
   
setTimeout(clearInterval,2000,interval);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

In your case it will be like

```
const timerId = setInterval(navigator.mozMobileMessage.send,10000,mobileNumberInput.value, "Hello");
setTimeout(() => {clearInterval(timerId);},
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Yuvaraj M. New to JS and didn't realise how to call a function with parameters using setinterval :(

Comment: Accept my answer @waj